# A question about eigenvalue equation of Hankel transform

Tags: integration

When we think about the Fourier transform in two dimensional polar coordinates, the Hankel transform is the transformation with respect to the polar diameter. Now I have a question, why is the following expression invariant for the Hankel transform? And How to prove this equation?

$\exp \left(-\frac{1}{2} x\right) x^{m / 2} L_{p}^{m}(x)=\frac{1}{2}(-1)^{p} \int_{0}^{+\infty} \mathrm{d} y \exp \left(-\frac{1}{2} y\right) J_{m}(\sqrt{x y}) y^{m / 2} L_{p}^{m}(y)$

$L_{p}^{m}(y)$ is Laguerre function. m, p is order;

$J_{m}(\sqrt{x y})$ is Bessel function with order of m.

[L. Yu et al., The Laguerre-Gaussian series representation of two-dimensional fractional Fourier transform. Journal of Physics A: Mathematical and General 31, 9353-9357 (1998).](http://iopscience.iop.org/0305-4470/31/46/025)

Comment: The first part is trivial (why is). The Hankel transform is its own inverse. Just apply the Hankel transform and you are done. I agree you should ask on math.se

Answer (score 0):

**Q:**  How to prove this equation?

**A:** An explicit proof, of a more general identity, is in [On a Hankel Transform Integral containing an Exponential Function and
Two Laguerre Polynomials](https://cds.cern.ch/record/279205/files/cn-95-004.pdf). See Equation (5), and take $\sigma=0$, $m=n$.

[image]

Another special case ($m=n$, $\nu=2\sigma$) was discussed at [MSE](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4058585/87355), with a reference to a 1936 paper by Watson, [An Integral Equation for the Square of a Laguerre Polynomial](https://doi.org/10.1112/jlms/s1-11.4.256)